# Jquery click eventObject does not work in Firefox

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, firefox, onclick, cross-browser

I am trying to get the text from an element that is clicked on. The *javascript/jquery* works on *IE* and *chrome* but does not work in *Firefox*.

**HTML**

```
<span class="spanclass">Click Me</span>
<br/>
<span id="displayDel"></span>
```

**Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.spanclass').click( function(cl) {
        onSelect(cl.delegateTarget);
    });
});

function onSelect(cldel)
{
    $('#displayDel').text("You "+cldel.innerText);
}
```

Here is a running example in JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/FdXNg/

In *IE* and *Chrome* when you click "Click Me" it says "You Click Me".

In *Firefox* when you click "Click Me" it says `You undefined`

How could I make this work in *IE, Chrome*, and *FireFox*?

Comment: Why not using property innerHTML or any other method supported by Firefox? Equivalent of innerText in FF is `textContent` but use a cross browser solution. Checking that in google would give you an aswer in less than 15 sec...

Comment: @roasted The example I gave above was a simplified version of my actual code. The real code has html in the span that I do not want. The objectEvent is different in FF and Chrome therefore I though that was the problem. I was Googleing "Jquery click EventObject firefox"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you use an external function? This will do the same (with the `.text()` function of jQuery):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.spanclass').click( function() {
       $('#displayDel').text("You "+$(this).text());
    });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/FdXNg/1/

If you want to hide the element after click, add this after the 3th rule of the code:

```
       $(this).hide(); //or `remove()`
```

**EDIT** (after comment)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.spanclass').click(function() {
        onSelect($(this));
    });
});

function onSelect(cldel) {
    $('#displayDel').text("You "+cldel.text());
}
```

Comment: The example I gave was simplified. The real onSelect is called from other functions but this worked. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try `$('#displayDel').text("You "+$(cldel).html());` this is more like the jquery way. ;)

Comment: If you want to use jquery, text() method would be more appropriate here, just like in Pieter's answer

Comment: The example I gave was a simplified version of my acutal code. There is actually html in the span that I do not want. Thanks for you answer though.

Comment: @Nick so use `$(cldel).text()`

Comment: Indeed. There is no difference if there are no tags inside the span. But you never know when you might change your mind and place some tags. Nice point.